# Trying to redo my Eclipse "installation"

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to delete the folder that I unzipped eclipse into (I did it on the desktop for easy access). Every time I try, I get an error saying that it cannot be done because the folder or a file in it is open in another program. I have no programs running at all, and I still can't delete the folder. I am using Windows 8, Eclipse Juno, and am trying to download the C/C++ version so that I can do C++(got the CDT plugin, but can't find g++). Now, all I really want to do is completely get rid of Eclipse so I can start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to solve the issue about not being able to delete the folder.